# How can I avoid accidental right-clicks now that the Macbook trackpad is so big?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, preferences, contextual-menu

I just bought a summer-2018 Macbook Pro, with a very big trackpad.

The result is that I frequently experience accidental right-clicks when I click but one of my other fingers is touching the trackpad.

**Is there a way to change the area where it is possible to double click or do something else to avoid this hyper-sensitivity?**

It is especially a problem in Photoshop where I frequently get secondary menus when I just want to move something.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it has always existed, but in OS X Mojave there is a trackpad setting that solved this problem for me:

[image]

Changing **Secondary Click** to **Bottom Right Corner** means that **clicking with two fingers no longer works**.

It makes the trackpad function more like a traditional trackpad with a right button below it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm tempted to create a plate/stencil to sit on top of the trackpad, to shrink the exposed space -- and see if that fixes these annoying problems.  Anyone ever try that?   This large trackpad was a bad design decision -- everyone that I know with the same macbook pro hates it.